# FragmentTransaction between single Fragment and a ViewPager of Fragments is slow

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmenttransaction

So I'm noticing serious slow downs in the FragmentTransaction (specifically onBackPressed()) between a single fragment and a ViewPager of fragments.

Here are some timing details:

1) ParentActivity has a single Fragment which has a ViewPager of Fragments.
2) Perform FragmentTransaction to replace above ViewPager with another single Fragment.
3) Press back (onBackPressed()) reverts above FragmentTransaction so now we're back in the first state.

In this example, performing step 3), specifically onBackPressed() takes at least 150 ms.  This is ridiculously long!  However, I've noticed that if in step 2) the fragment transaction led to replacing the original ViewPager with a different ViewPager, then the onBackPressed() in 3) performed much better (i.e. <80ms).

That is, switching from a ViewPager inside a Fragment to another ViewPager inside the same Fragment performs decently, however, when switching between a ViewPager of Fragments to a simple Fragment the performance of onBackPressed() is significantly worsened.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare so I used TraceView to try and understand where the slowdown is occurring.  I specifically looked at onBackPressed.  Could you help me understand the result.  Basically I see that onBackPressed takes 528 in CPU time. Of this 98% of processing time is taken by FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState.  This leads to performOnCreate and performOnResume which each take approx. 43% of processing time. These each lead back to moveToState.  I'm not sure what I can get out of this.  The default implementation is simply taking a long time to execute the fragment transaction, but why?